# Need help resolving ESD problem

Tags: esd

**The Problem**
I’m having ESD issues.  Specifically, my device is failing when 4KV is repeated discharge on the aluminum enclosure of my device. I have already made improvements to harden my design, but I want to look for other areas that might be causing me troubles.

One possible issue is that my power board might be acting as an antenna, transferring EMF to the power management IC. Completely redesigning my device so that everything is on the same board would be the best solution, but for a multitude of reasons, I need to stick with current design described below.

Does the way I bring in my external power look like trouble?  If so, is there anything I can do to mitigate the problems? Thank-you in advance for any help you can provide.

**The Device**
My device is a portable USB device that can be powered over USB but also via a 9V DC connection.  The device consists of two boards inside an aluminum enclosure.  As this is a portable USB device, there is no earth ground.

The main board (4 layer) has all the digital and analog circuitry for my design.  The top board (2 layer) supports the 9V DC connector and a LDO to bring the voltage down to 5V before going into the main board.  The reason I’m using the power board at all is due to a lack of space on the main board and the need to be able to properly cool the LDO, which needs to be able to supply up to 500ma of power.
I’m including pics of the boards, showing how they are connected, as well as schematics for the power board and the power section of the main board.

[image: Power and Main board]
[image: Schematic for the Power Board]
[image: Schematic for the Power Section on the Main Board]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I've added a pic of the enclosure.  It's all around the boards, but I left out the back panel so you can get a better idea of how things are aligned.  I've also changed 'chassis ground' to 'earth ground'.

Comment: Does it only happen when you do multiple zaps? Are you bleeding of the DUT in between zaps? Because you are allowed to do that.

Comment: No, the tester was touching the ESD gun directly to one of the screws holding the enclosure together and repeatedly discharging 25 times at a rate of about 1 discharge / 0.5 seconds.  I personally thought that was a bit harsh.

Comment: Where is the case connected  to your circuit?

Comment: It isn't connected.  That might very well be the issue.  I will spin another prototype and make sure my shielded connectors have a low impedance path back to the enclosure.  From an assembly perspective, it would be a lot easier if I didn't have to connect back to the enclosure.  Isn't there an effective way to attenuate the ESD on the PCB?

Comment: @RobertJonkman No, use the enclosure. PCB methods are inferior. They rely on the free capacitance of the ground plane, the same ground plane your ESD sensitive components are on and want to keep ESD currents out of. Sometimes they add a thin metal plate as chassis ground if non-conducting enclosure is used just to increase the free space capacitance and keep the ESD currents out of the ground plane. ESD is very high current and frequency and capacitvely couples into everything and stuff on PCB is too close together to stop it.

Comment: In Henry Ott's book it listed a bunch of approaches from conducting/ininsulating enclosures, with and without metal plates or ground planes. It basically said if you have no conducting plate, conducting enclosure, or ground plane then you are screwed. Your two layer board might give an opportunity to use it as a chassis plane but it must be very sparsely populated to come anywhere close to the safety of the enclosure. Then you add TVS diodes to suppress the ESD in the chassis ground, whatever the chassis ground is.

Comment: It may also be a good idea to figure out in what way the board is failing. Is a floating reset pin getting asserted? Is a floating interrupt getting actuated and the code goes off into a non-existent ISR? Sometimes one or two little capacitors on digital inputs can solve ESD problems.

Comment: Some connectors may be designed to make contact with the enclosure via spring loaded metal pieces. This could simplify assembly. You can often use metallic tape to prototype things like this prior to actual design changes. You can buy copper tape with conductive adhesive, or just clip wires (keep them short) from point A to point B.

Comment: I've added an image of my updated layout around the connectors. I have left two through holes for places where I might connect a wire to ground back to the enclosure, as well as some options to add some filtering.  What about the layers under the connectors?  Should I leave them as is, or should I notch them out to they don't overlap the tiny chassis ground I've made?

Comment: So the part that failed is the reverse current protection MOSFET (DMG2305UX-13) on the 2 layer power board.  I guess a MOSFET is not the right solution there.

Comment: The MOSFET failed. OK, it looks like you have TVS on one side and a big capacitor on the other. Maybe the TVS needs to kick in at a lower voltage. You could add a capacitor in parallel with it, also. And even better, you may want to put TVS from gate to source on the MOSFET (back-to-back Zener type TVS). The gate to source capacitance is very fragile with respect to over-voltage.

Comment: I'm guessing that the ESD arced from the casing onto the ground pin the of that DC connector, and killed the MOSFET.  I can handle the voltage drop and the heat, so I'll replace the MOSFET with a schottky diode (SM5817PL-TP) and be sure to cut those legs down.  Do you think that would be more robust?

Comment: Probably. Certainly worth a try (you can probably get the diode in there as a rework to validate it prior to changing the board design).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to get the device to pass ESD testing, without grounding to the enclosure.  I'm not entirely sure what made the difference, but I thought I would share a list of the changes I made to harden the device.

- I filled the top and bottom layers of my 4-layer PCB with as much well stitched ground as possible.
- I trimmed off the legs of connectors to keep them away from the enclosure.
- I added a 1000 pF capacitor to my RESET line.
- I made a separate copper landing area for my USB connectors and I connected that to the rest of the ground through a ferrite in parallel with a 1000 pF and 0.1 uF capacitor.
- I added a couple 10 uF capacitors near my active components to serve as extra global capacitance.

I hope this is useful information.

Answer (score 4):

> As this is a portable USB device, there is no chassis ground.

This is wrong. Your conductive enclosure *is* the chassis ground. ESD design does not happen independently of the enclosure.

You carefully select which ground points on your circuit will be connected to the enclosure as chassis ground in order to maximize the free space capacitance so a ESD charge introduced to it will change the voltage as little as possible.

At the same time, you have to select these point so that an ESD discharge won't flow from your enclosure *through* your board. This means grounding like panel-mounted connectors and switches to the enclosure, and not your PCB. Sometimes it also means having a small split plane on your PCB where the split plane is well connected to the enclosure and acts as an extension of chassis GND so ESD currents don't flow through your actual circuit ground, though this is not applicable to your case.

Also, the TVS diodes are supposed to connect the pin on each connector and switch directly to chassis GND. This includes the GND pin on connectors. I know, it's pretty weird. You might have to sit there staring at things for a while to try and figure out how a common mode ESD flows into and charges everything in your system.

Painting the enclosure in an insulating paint also helps.

Comment: Thank-you for the feedback.  From the responses that I'm getting, it seems that my issues are not related to having the sperate power board.

Answer (score 2):

The general advise to solve ESD-related problems is to connect all exposed metal areas to a chassis ground or a shield etc. Otherwise the charge has nowhere to go, which may result in nearby electronics getting affected or damaged.

It's not really clear how you connect the boards to chassis, but you should ground it to the boards.

To fix this in an existing system in the simplest possible way, I would place a wire on the voltage ground connector, connect it to a cable lug, drill a hole through the chassis, then connect the cable lug against the chassis with a screw+nut. At least try this to see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this does not exactly answer your question. But I have had to fight ESD problems about half a dozen times. In most cases, they were fixable by attaching capacitors or RC filters to digital inputs. This is because in most cases, the mechanism of ESD failure was unwanted state transition on a digital input that caused a reset or other undesirable behavior for the device under test (DUT). In none of these cases were the failures permanent damage type of failures (although I have seen that also).

You don't say what your failure mechanism actually is. Can it be recovered by re-powering the DUT? If so, then you really should determine exactly what is happening to cause the failure. Some likely candidates are pins that can generate interrupts to the processor, reset pins, pins that enable power supplies, etc. Any of these pins, if not properly terminated, can experience an unwanted logic level transition during an ESD event, causing a reset or other haywire behavior. Sometimes one chip on a board may reset while other chips do not, and as a result they are out of sync with each other.

Proper termination means a robust pullup or pulldown, and/or a small capacitor placed close to the input (for example 22 or 100 pF). If the input is not actually used, then you can use 1nF or so. For connections which go off-board, a series resistance or RF choke may be helpful also, if the signal can tolerate it.

The worst offenders would be input pins with long traces attached to them and no strong driving source. The long traces provide more opportunity for the ESD energy to couple in to the input.

If actual hardware damage is occurring (not recoverable from power cycling) then you should figure out exactly where that damage is occurring to get a better idea of the failure mode. Once you do that, specific countermeasures will likely become more obvious.

Comment: I've bough Henry Ott's book and I'm reading.  While he highly recommends grounding back to the enclosure, he also has loads of suggestions similar to what you have said to harden the system.  I will implement those recommendation as well as a method to ground back to the enclosure and I'll go back for another round of testing with 2 DUTs.  The failure state was resolved with a power cycle, but there definitely was some permanent damage because now sometimes the power just randomly cuts out.  That's why I was suspicious of the power management IC.  I will do some more investigating.

Comment: If there is some way to figure out what exactly is damaged by comparing known good units with faulty ones, that would definitely help you find where the hardening is needed. Also, I agree with others for the most part. I just posted this answer because I felt maybe it would address your immediate needs better even if it doesn't directly answer your question.